# Evergreen load errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have a **Rails 5** app and just added the following line to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'evergreen', require: 'evergreen/rails'
```

After that I run:

```
bundle
rake
```

And get the following issues:

### Issue #1

*Relevant output:*

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rack/showexceptions
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/showexceptions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/evergreen-0.3.0/lib/evergreen.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

I've 'fixed' this by using sinatra's master branch (currently at 2.0.0.beta2)

```
gem 'sinatra', git: 'https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra.git'
```

### Issue #2:

*Relevant output:*

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- capybara/wait_until
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/Users/veronicarebagliatte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ticketing_system/gems/evergreen-0.3.0/lib/evergreen.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

Thing is `wait_until` has been [removed from capybara](https://www.varvet.com/blog/why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara).

Please note I'm not proceeding with evergreen actual usage just yet, all I want is to install it successfully for now. In other words, I want to be able to run `rake` without getting any errors.

Has someone else experienced the same issues? Is there anything I'm missing or should I just fork the gem and try to fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error log you can see that you're project is using evergreen v0.3.0 (because its sinatra restriction was the last one that would allow 2+), whereas the current version of evergreen is v1.2.0 -  You need to lock your version of evergreen in your Gemfile to >=1.2.0 and then see what other dependence issues you have.
  You'll have at least a dependence issue with sinatra since the 1.2.0 version of evergreen requires sinatra ~> 1.1 whereas the current master branch allows >= 1.1.  To use the master branch of evergreen in your project specify

```
gem 'evergreen', github: 'abepetrillo/evergreen', require: 'evergreen/rails'
```

in your Gemfile

Comment: I'm afraid when doing this and running `bundle` I get the following message: `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack"`. You can reproduce this adding evergreen to the gemfile of a brand new Rails 5 app.

Comment: @rebagliatte By looking at the conflicts shown you can see that it all boils down to actionpack requiring rack 2.x and sinatra 1.4.6 needing rack 1.x . If you use the master branch of evergreen and the master of sinatra it will fix that conflict - whether or not you'll run into other issues is anyones guess since you're trying to use a gem thats not officially supporting rails 5 yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `wait_until` has removed with capybara2.0 check [this updates](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/aab9825c0a25f27d25c9be2da8077e5f33ca5597/History.md). You should remove `require "capybara/wait_until"` for success.